# Connect to RPC Server in Docker

Tags: windows, docker, rpc

Getting started with docker for Windows.
Would like to manage/monitor the stop the service in the container with a Services snap-in.

```
    FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
    EXPOSE 135 1024-65535
```

The container was run with

```
docker run -it --host-name rpc-test myrpc cmd
```

RPCSS Server works on the container.

```
sc query RPCSS
```

Still getting the error:
**1722: The RPC server is unavailable**

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Ok. Have found a reply from server in WireShark

nca_s_fault_access_denied

Any ideas?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just start and stop the container?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set port with `-p` argument. `EXPOSE` doesn't open a port, it's an informational directive. Here is the documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose

> This exposes port 80 of the container without publishing the port to the host system’s interfaces.